# Grey background color when clicked

Tags: css, internet-explorer-10

I have these CSS definition for my buttons:

```css
nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    margin-right: 0px;
    font-size: 19px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    /* border:1px solid red; */
}
```

In Internet Explorer 10, it gets a grey background when clicked. Why?

Comment: There can only be ONE simple answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13608716/css-internet-explorer-10#comment18658773_13608716

Comment: //border:1px solid red; If you wanted to comment it it should be */border:1px solid red;*/

Comment: have you used any kind of normalize or cssreset or not!?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a:active { background: none; } to your stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer 10 seems to display links (anchors: i.e. `<a href>`), which has the property `display:block;` with a grey background when clicked.

You can remove this easily by inserting `background-color:none;` into your code. So, you should have the following code:

```
nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    margin-right: 0px;
    font-size: 19px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    /* border:1px solid red; */
    background-color:none;
}
```

On the positive, the problem should be removed. Two negatives include that, you cannot set a background, or have an active state in Internet Explorer (i.e. `a:active`). Other browsers will continue to work perfectly normal/fine.

Answer (score -2):

Still we could not understand what about the question is? Which `background color` is `gray`? You didn't provide your `html` too. I guess this bit of code would help you to change or remove the `color` of the links will change the behavior in each states...

```
a:link    {color:red;}
a:visited {color:green;}
a:hover   {color:blue;}
a:active  {color:yellow;}
```

With this four colors you could check yourself and come to the conclusion... :)

Comment: It's an Internet Explorer 10 thing. Doesn't have anything to do with the HTML.

Comment: @minitech: IE10 "is not eqaul to" HTML. Haha. Good one.